# Selecting items in Outliner using hotkey (B)?

Tags: outliner

I select multiple items using the <kbd>B</kbd> in the outliner window, but when I want to parent them (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> 
) to the last selected object (I select object seperatley, <kbd>LMB</kbd> 
), it won't parent.

Just to clarify - this is for organization sake - got lots of WGT from an armature, I just want to store them hidden from the outliner.

Comment: When you're trying to parent, is the cursor over the outliner or the 3D view?

Comment: AS per the answer by @DuarteFarrajotaRamos , do the B selection in the Outliner, then move the cursor over the 3D View and Ctrl + P for parenting, the only thing is you SHOULD have the cursor over the 3D View window, not over the Outliner window, keep in mind Blender's functionality is relative to the type of the View.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> for parenting only works in the 3D view As far as I know, not in the outliner, so pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in the outliner will not work only directly in the viewport.

There are other ways to do this if you want to do it directly from the outliner though, you could use <kbd>B</kbd> for selecting as you already do, then click and drag&drop to parent by clicking on the object's icon to the left and dragging from there over to another object you want to parent the selection to.

Would this work for you?

**Edit** I was just made aware that it only parents one object at a time though, so it may not suit your needs entirely.

Comment: Dragging in the Outliner for parenting works, but keep in mind you can not drag multiple objects, you have to do them one by one.

Comment: True, wasn't aware of that, thanks for the explanation. I'll update the answer accordingly.